# How to slow down a part of a video clip in adobe premiere

Tags: adobe-premiere

when i use the speed option on a video clip in premiere, it always slows down the complete clip. but i would like to have just a part of it slow

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the razor tool to split the clip at the begin and end points of the section that you want to slow down. Then apply the speed option to the that sub-clip.

Comment: Is there a way to slow it down smoothly?